# HP P812 attr_value_interface_phy_not_connected

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, scsi

We got an error on HP server with a HP Smart Array P812 and now 6 of the drives are missing.
the error seems to be attr_value_interface_phy_not_connected (See pic) and I found no reference anywhere on the web for it.
in status alerts windows it also says "Bay 0 is bad or missing" for all the drives.

[image]

Comment: What model server is this?

Answer (score 0):

The error you see is just an undefined variable in the web application. That's a programming problem. But the fact remains that the systems doesn't think the drives are connected.

It may be more useful for you to see what's happening physically on the server.

I count 12 disks. **Is this a ProLiant DL180 G6 server?**

I ask because of the age of the controller, the drive size, count and potential for backplane issues.

- When did this start happening?
- Is your firmware up-to-date?
- Are all of the disk status lights illuminated? What color are they?
- Look at the BIOS when the system boots. What are the POST errors?
- Look in the HP IML log. What is it reporting?
- Look inside the server. How many cables are connected between the backplane and the RAID controller? Are they secure?